# Horizontal scrolling skin for mediawiki

Tags: microsoft-metro, mediawiki, skin, mediawiki-templates

I want to create a mediawiki horizontal scrolling skin based on the wikipedia metro app.

[wikipedia metro github](https://github.com/wikimedia/WikipediaMobile/tree/master/WikipediaMetro/WikipediaMetroTest)

[video of wikipedia metro](https://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/Mobile/Windows_8_Metro)

The skin is intented for a normal website and not a metro app.So how can i convert the code that is already created for mediawiki platform to a skin i can use?Where should i start.I tried to understand the metro app and convert it but i cant figure out how it works.Can you give some guidelines.(I am on linux computer so i cant test the app itself)
I can't find any other horizontal scrolling skins for mediawiki.

Answer (score 2):

The Windows 8 app is not just a skin, it's a separate HTML page. It uses the API (specifically [the `mobileview` module](https://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/Extension%3aMobileFrontend#action.3Dmobileview) from the MobileFrontend extension). It also uses WinJS (JS library specific to Windows 8 apps).

I'm not sure if it's suitable for a full-fledged skin (like Vector), but I think you could use it as a base for a separate view of your wiki. Most of the work you will have to do would be replacing Windows 8-specific stuff, like WinJS.

Most of the HTML code seems to be in [`default.html`](https://github.com/wikimedia/WikipediaMobile/blob/master/WikipediaMetro/WikipediaMetroTest/default.html) and most of the JavaScript that actually runs the app is in [`default.js`](https://github.com/wikimedia/WikipediaMobile/blob/master/WikipediaMetro/WikipediaMetroTest/js/default.js).

Comment: The most relevant bit is probably the CSS styles -- the multicolumn stuff is I think usable on other browsers and could be applied to the wiki's content area.